# facebook doesn't make notifications when making invite + invite to different url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website and I wish to make "invite friends" button for this website. Therefore I created facebook app and in the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" / "Website with Facebook Login" section I configured my url.

Then I made a call to facebook apprequest:

```
   FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            title: 'my title',
            message: my message'
        }, calback);
```

The problem is that the recipients didn't get any notification about this invite. They can go to app requests and see the request, but I would like them to get a notification. How can I do that?

Another thing, what if I want the link on the notification to be different then the "Website with Facebook Login" parameter?

Comment: User-to-user are only available for canvas apps, and will always go to the canvas URL.

Comment: @CBroe: And what if I don't have facebook app but only a web application?

Comment: Then you can’t use requests. You could set up a canvas page for your app as well, just to receive the requests and then redirect to your web application – but be aware that canvas apps whose sole or main purpose is to direct the user away from Facebook are against Platform Policies.